# Disable access to printers

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

In the below pic, if the user clicks the "Printers" button the Control Panel Printer window opens up.  I've tried every GPO I can find to turn this off, but nothing seems to work.  I've tried
User Config - Admin Templates - Control Panel:
Hide specified Control Panel Items
Prohibit access to the Control Panel

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you verified accessing the control panel (control.exe) is denied by the operating system, when activating the "*Prohibit access to the Control Panel*" rule? It seems very wierd to me, that this is still possible, while opening control.exe is denied! Especially "*control.exe /name Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters*" and "*control.exe printers*"

Comment: I can access the windows\system32 folder once I get the printers window and when I try to run control.exe, you're right, it's denied by the OS, I only had Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters, so I changed it to the full text has you have and still able the Printers button allows access.  Would it be because I'm inside my application?

Comment: added second picture showing GPO values

Comment: "*Hide specific Control Panel items*" does only hide the items. You do not need that policy, if you have enabled "*Prohibit access to the Control Panel*". But I do not know why you are able to open that particular windows.

Comment: strange for sure, I was able to prevent the button from doing anything by taking ownership of the windows\system32 folder and deny access by group on prnfldr.dll, but I'm not a big fan of taking ownership etc

Comment: You are right, taking ownership of the system32 folder is a really stupid thing to do.